# Replace parts of string that occur within a list

Tags: python, string

Alright I'm making a program that needs to take information about a customer from a user, there are various fields that need to be filled in. And if the values of the alphanumeric values are left blank I need to by default set that value to blank, so a single whitesapce character. And I need to make it equal to `0` if the numeric values are left blank

```
    def insertion(new_record):
    field_names = ['Customer_ID=',
    'Last_Name=',
    'First_Name=',
    'Street_Address=',
    'City=',
    'Province=',
    'Postal_Code=',
    ]
    field_names2 = ['Home_Phone=',
    'Business_Phone=']

    if new_record[3:5] == 'CU':
        for i in field_names:
            if i in new_record:
                new_record.replace()
```

The idea here is that I have list of the what the field names would look like if there were left blank by the user. So if any of those items in `field_names` or `numeric_field_names` appear in the string then it means the user left that field blank. And I want to replace those strings in the input accordingly, then write them to a file. Can I iterate through `new_record` in this case to replace those strings? Note also that the input will be multiple lines always.

**EDIT**

This is how I call the function:

```
insertion('''IN CU
Customer_ID=474
Last_Name=Sanderson
First_Name=John
Street_Address=17 Chestwood Ave
City=Scarborough
Province=Ont
Postal_Code=M9C2C7
Home_Phone=416/227-3297
Business_Phone=416/997-2923
//'''
)
```

Comment: what is the structure of  new_record? and give example of your output.

Comment: @user3 Sorry I added an example of what `new_record` might look like. The only output would be changing the field values if they were blank and writing it to a file

Comment: Can't you pass the parameters in separately and for each of them, in the function definition, eg def test(name=" ", height=100): will set these as the default value unless the user passes something in

Comment: Try to use more pythonic approach, like dictionary. You can parse your input with something like `dict(line.strip().split('=') for line in data.splitlines() if '=' in line)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using list, you can use dictionary in the following way.

```
def insertion(new_record):
    newRecordDict={r.split('=')[0]:r.split('=')[1] for r in new_record.split('\n')[1:-1]} #first and last line is ignored
    field_names = {'Customer_ID':None,
    'Last_Name':None,
    'First_Name':None,
    'Street_Address':None,
    'City':None,
    'Province':None,
    'Postal_Code':None,
    }
    field_names2 = {'Home_Phone':0,'Business_Phone':0}

    for field in field_names:
        field_names[field] = newRecordDict.get(field,None)
    for field in field_names2:
        field_names2[field] = newRecordDict.get(field,None)

    print field_names
    print field_names2
```

Actually, you can keep all data in to one dictioanary instead of field_names and field_names2.You can take a call for the same. In the above code, all data coming from the user loaded as dictionary in newRecordDict after that based on updated field, field_names and field_names2 gets updated.  Following is the output:

```
{'Province': 'Ont', 'City': 'Scarborough', 'First_Name': 'John', 'Last_Name': 'Sanderson', 'Postal_Code': 'M9C2C7', 'Customer_ID': '474', 'Street_Address': '17 Chestwood Ave'} 

{'Business_Phone': '416/997-2923', 'Home_Phone': '416/227-3297'}
```

Now, if you want to access 'Province' from field_names, you can use:

```
field_names['Province']
```

which returns 'Ont'. Similarly it works for all other fields.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the answer. But I misintepreted the question I'm supposed to answer. What is actually going to happen is as follows:

Comment: The user will have a file named `xactions.two` here's the example: http://pastebin.com/C3iSdNPT Each transaction there is terminated with `//`. So I need to search through that file and replace any empty fields with blanks or zeroes like in this example, and write the new updated version to a new file. Would I be able to alter your program?